# Mongoose expose only some virtuals to JSON

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know, I can expose all virtuals doing

```
var schemaOptions = {
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
};
```

the main problem is this also expose a virtual `id`, how can I defined only some virtuals toJSON?. something like

```
var schemaOptions = {
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: {
       thisOne: true
    }
  }
};
```

It doesn't work, sadly